# Is the ''o'' in ''osara'' (plate) an honorific o 御 or just a normal o お?

Tags: words, orthography, nouns, honorifics

I have learned that "plate" is both *sara* and *osara*.

The fact that the *o* can be attached implies to me that it is an honorific *o* 御.

My dictionary gives the honorific *o* as 御 but for *osara* it gives it as お.

Is "plate" written as both おさら and 御さら?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *osara*, the *o* is indeed honorific and it is commonly written in *kana* as お, but sometimes also as 御. As you are likely aware, there is often some flexibility in choosing between *kanji*, *hiragana* and *katakana* to write any given text.

As for *osara*, it would usually be written as お皿, because the honorific *o* is usually written お and because *sara* is usually written 皿 (this *kanji* is taught already in third grade of primary school). As I mentioned, deviations are possible, but I would say that 御さら is actually a combination you will basically never come across in real life. (Note that 御 is not taught until secondary school.)

The same would be true about *ocha* "tea", which will usually be written お茶, sometimes 御茶, rarely おちゃ and never 御ちゃ.

Comment: To add some perspective, both the official Jōyō list and the newspaper corrections of it actually prescribe not to use the kanji 御 unless the reading is ゴ, ギョ, or おん. So, both お and み are to be written in kana. Of course, the actual usage varies.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely お in お皿 is an example of so called 女房言葉 - basically a way of making words sound "polite" or "fancy" by using the お prefix. There are many other examples used in everyday Japanese: おでん、おかか、おこわ、おはぎ etc.